# XmlSchemaValidationException: This is an invalid xsi:type 'Book' when trying to deserialize an XML validating it with an XSD schema

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

I have an xml with an array of LibraryAssets, those are Books, Newspapers and Patents, and LibraryAsset is the abstract class they derive from.
I created an xsd schema based on that xml using visual studio's Create schema.
But when I try to deserialize the xml validating that it matches the schema I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : There is an error in XML document (3, 4).
  ----> System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException : This is an invalid xsi:type 'Book'.
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
```

My xsd schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="ArrayOfLibraryAsset">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="LibraryAsset">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="Id" type="xsd:unsignedInt" />
                            <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string" />
                            <xsd:element name="YearPublished" type="xsd:unsignedShort" />
                            <xsd:element name="PagesNumber" type="xsd:unsignedByte" />
                            <xsd:element name="Annotation" type="xsd:string" />
                            <xsd:element name="Price" type="xsd:unsignedByte" />
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Number" type="xsd:string" />
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Inventors">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="string" type="xsd:string" />
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Country" type="xsd:string" />
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ApplicationDate" type="xsd:dateTime" />
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="StandardNumber" type="xsd:string" />
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Authors">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="string" type="xsd:string" />
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="CityPublished" type="xsd:string" />
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Publisher" type="xsd:string" />
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="CopiesNumber" type="xsd:unsignedShort" />
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Issue" type="xsd:unsignedByte" />
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="IssueDate" type="xsd:dateTime" />
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfLibraryAsset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <LibraryAsset xsi:type="Book">
    <Id>62915385</Id>
    <Name>Unspecified</Name>
    <YearPublished>2000</YearPublished>
    <PagesNumber>200</PagesNumber>
    <Annotation>No annotation.</Annotation>
    <Price>50</Price>
    <StandardNumber>000-0-00-000000-0</StandardNumber>
    <Authors>
      <string>Author</string>
    </Authors>
    <CityPublished>Unspecified</CityPublished>
    <Publisher>Unspecified</Publisher>
    <CopiesNumber>300</CopiesNumber>
  </LibraryAsset>
  <LibraryAsset xsi:type="Newspaper">
    <Id>57188600</Id>
    <Name>Unspecified</Name>
    <YearPublished>2021</YearPublished>
    <PagesNumber>25</PagesNumber>
    <Annotation>No annotation.</Annotation>
    <Price>5</Price>
    <StandardNumber>0000-0000</StandardNumber>
    <CityPublished>Unspecified</CityPublished>
    <Publisher>Unspecified</Publisher>
    <CopiesNumber>1500</CopiesNumber>
    <Issue>10</Issue>
    <IssueDate>2021-11-19T00:00:00+04:00</IssueDate>
  </LibraryAsset>
  <LibraryAsset xsi:type="Patent">
    <Id>14464371</Id>
    <Name>Unspecified</Name>
    <YearPublished>2021</YearPublished>
    <PagesNumber>50</PagesNumber>
    <Annotation>No annotation.</Annotation>
    <Price>10</Price>
    <Number>X0000000</Number>
    <Inventors>
      <string>Inventor</string>
    </Inventors>
    <Country>Unspecified</Country>
    <ApplicationDate>2021-11-19T00:00:00+04:00</ApplicationDate>
    <IssueDate>2021-11-18T19:34:16.5902406+04:00</IssueDate>
  </LibraryAsset>
</ArrayOfLibraryAsset>
```

Xml deserialization:

```
var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add(null, shemaFilePath);
Exception exception = null;
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
    Schemas = schemas,
    ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
    ValidationFlags =
        XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints |
        XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings
};
settings.ValidationEventHandler += delegate (object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
    {
        _log.Warning(args.Message);
    }
    else
    {
        exception ??= args.Exception;
        _log.Error(exception);
        throw exception;
    }
};
using var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
using var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fileStream, settings);
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
data = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader) as List<T>;
```

Comment: You are saying you have an abstract type libraryassets which is abstract. Your XSD tells something different, it tals only it has a complex type LibraryAssets, it tels nowhere that book is derived from it?

Comment: @Aldert how do I tell it then? LibraryAsset class in my project has a tag [XmlInclude(typeof(Book))]. If I should add something to the xsd also, then what might it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is much more simple then I thought it would be.

So, basically, I just had to declare each type (Book, Newspaper, Patent being extensions of abstract LibraryAsset). The final solution XSD looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="LibraryAsset" type="LibraryAsset" abstract="true"/>
    <xs:element name="Book" type="Book"/>
    <xs:element name="Newspaper" type="Newspaper"/>
    <xs:element name="Patent" type="Patent"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="LibraryAsset" abstract="true">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Id" type="xsd:int" />
            <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="YearPublished" type="xsd:int" />
            <xsd:element name="PagesNumber" type="xsd:int" />
            <xsd:element name="Annotation" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="Price" type="xsd:int" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Number" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Inventors">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="string" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Country" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ApplicationDate" type="xsd:dateTime" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="StandardNumber" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Authors">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="string" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="CityPublished" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Publisher" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="CopiesNumber" type="xsd:int" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Issue" type="xsd:int" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="IssueDate" type="xsd:dateTime" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="Book">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="LibraryAsset">

            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="Newspaper">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="LibraryAsset">

            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="Patent">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="LibraryAsset">

            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="ArrayOfLibraryAsset">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="LibraryAsset">
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, your schema generator has a limitation that it ignores `xsi:type` attributes. That's not a great surprise, it's hard to know what it would do with them.

You obviously know something that the tool doesn't ("LibraryAssets are Books, Newspapers and Patents, and LibraryAsset is the abstract class they derive from") and it's normal practice that when you generate a schema, what you get is only a first cut, and you're expected to edit it to take account of your knowledge of the semantics of the application domain.

Comment: @Michael_Kay I'm trying to find what to do in this case, but I'm still unsuccessful. Maybe you can give me a hint on how to let it know what I expect? I tried to name the element Book instead of LibraryAsset and add <xs:extension base="LibraryAsset"> to it, but then it says "The element 'ArrayOfLibraryAsset' has invalid child element 'LibraryAsset'. List of possible elements expected: 'Book, Newspaper, Patent'."

Comment: If the only thing you want is for your document to pass validation, then define three types Books, Newspapers, and Patents that are trivial restrictions of the complex type of LibraryAsset (which will need to become a named global type).

Comment: @Michael_Kay I don't exactly understand what you mean by making them trivial restrictions, can you elaborate? Sorry for the incompetence, I just started learning xsd schemas yesterday.

Comment: Sorry, this site is for answering specific questions, not for giving an introductory tutorial. XSD is not easy to get to grips with (it took me at least six weeks), I would recommend reading Priscilla Walmsley's book.